# How can I create permission to 'is_staff' in Django?

Tags: django, django-admin

I have two, regular types of access to admin - one is 'is_staff', other one is 'is_staff' with 'is_superuser'. Superuser is fine, I am okay with admin having access to anything, but I would like users with 'is_staff' flag to automatically have some permissions, without having to add them. How can I achieve that? Should I create separate group that is added automatically once the person have 'is_staff' flag? Or can I attach some permissions automatically to 'is_staff' group?

Comment: Where do you plan on setting the `is_staff` flag for these users?

Answer (score 0):

You'd be looking at creating a group with the permissions for users with a positive `is_staff` attribute. Any user added to this group will automatically inherit the permissions given to the group.

To automatically add users to this group - use Django Signals. Here's a small example of what you'd be looking at:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def assign_group(sender, instance, created=False, **kwargs):
    if created and instance.is_staff:
    # add instance to the group (if is_staff is true and it is a new entry)
```

Link: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/signals/